# LINQ to SQL - Nullable INT in ForeignKey = "Cannot create an association..."

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreign-keys, associations

I have a table that has a primary key that's an INT... I have another table, that has a foreignkey relationship to that first table, but it's a NULLABLE INT.

This is perfectly ok, and 100% acceptable to SQL... however LINQ to SQL is complaining about mismatched types ("int to Nullable[int]").

Error Message: Cannot create an association "Store_People". Properties do not have matching types: "PersonID", "ID".

How do I solve this so that the designer stops yelling at a 100% correct usage of SQL?

Comment: In what context does this "complaining" occur?  Could we see a code sample or representative line that demonstrates the problem?  Or is it in SqlMetal or the DBML design surface?

Comment: Visual Studio... Add DBML... add two tables as described above... try to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I threw together. Table2's Table1Id column is a nullable foreign key to Table1.  I even threw in a few data records and tested some Linq queries...

[image]

*EDIT*: Since I'm getting some downvotes (apparently) for the broken link because this question is 6 years old and the host I used hasn't survived... here's an updated version.

Answer (score 8):

I found the problem. You can create the association ONLY if the parent class doesn't have the Nullable field as the key.

So, this:

[alt text http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=43d83ac4-707d-47fc-832c-588261e6a5d7](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=43d83ac4-707d-47fc-832c-588261e6a5d7)

will cause this error:

[alt text http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=19ed54aa-9f4f-4d5c-ba18-4996509d2da7](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=19ed54aa-9f4f-4d5c-ba18-4996509d2da7)

...but this:

[alt text http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=0e09affd-2134-4712-999b-7e792f6e081b](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/UserImage.aspx?ImageID=0e09affd-2134-4712-999b-7e792f6e081b)

will work perfectly.

That looks like a bug (or at least, a stupidity of LINQ to SQL)... but I love it other than that.

Comment: Not a bug, you were just associating them the wrong way round.

Comment: Effectively what you were trying to do, it sounds like, was set the dependent table as the parent and the table that *defined* the foreign key as the child - i.e., the relationship would work the opposite of your intent.  FWIW, SQL won't let you create a relationship like this either.

Comment: SQL will absolutely  let you create a nullable foreign key to a non-nullable primary key. I don't think this solution works as well as he thinks it does either.  You end up with a single object coming back, whereas having the association the other way around would give a LIST of objects back.

Comment: @Telos - However, you *CANNOT* select the one with the nullable, foreign key as the **parent**, which is what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I have precisely that situation in a DBML now, and it is working fine.

### Primary Key

- Nullable - False
- Primary Key - True
- Server Data type - int NOT NULL IDENTITY
- Type - int (System.Int32)

### Foreign Key

- Nullable - Trure
- Primary Key - False
- Server Data type - Int
- Type - int (System.Int32)    (actually defined as Nullable in the context.designer.cs file)